# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence with NetworkX

Tags: python, for-loop, max, min, networkx

I am attempting to determine the number of nodes (size) of the giant component of a network. I am doing this in a `for` loop where I evaluate the effects of a range of external loadings on the network itself - that's why you see a `for` loop below.

My code is as follows:

```
#create the graph G
import networkx as nx
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N) #N=100 and represents the side of a square grid
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() ) #Dictionary of all positions
#do stuff
giant_component=OrderedDict() #Dict with the size of the giant component for each simulation
for i,file in enumerate(os.listdir(directoryPath)):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
    #do stuff
    giant_component[file]=max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len) 
    #do stuff
```

But I get an error at the very first iteration:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\Scripts\Network_Scripts\Lattice_ForLoop.py in <module>()
    273         percent_total_active_nodes[file]=100*act_nodes_model/10000                  #Total (Stage 1 + Stage 2)
    274 
--> 275         giant_component[file]=max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len)     #Analysis (Stage 1 + Stage 2)
    276         largest_cc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
    277         network_diam[file]=len(largest_cc)                                          #Analysis (Stage 1 + Stage 2) = Diameter of the largest component

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

**Question:** What does `max() arg is an empty sequence` mean when associated with `max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len)`?

Comment: What is N? What does the graph contain? Do some basic debugging, and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I wish I could post an MCVE. My code is over 300 lines long! However, `N=100`, and the graph contains a regular grid of nodes.

Comment: If the graph is a grid, what's the point in looking for connected components?

Comment: We're going theoretical now :) This code was written for testing the response of a grid to a range of different loadings. Therefore, when the network is fragmented, you want to know about the size of the largest connected component.

Comment: So the graph doesn't contain a regular grid, but has been modified by code you haven't shown. In any case, if you don't provide a reproducible example you can't expect this to be answered.

Comment: MCVE doesn't mean post your entire code. It means to distill it into a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. The example you posted does not demonstrate the problem, so will not help anyone answer the question.

Comment: It is rather hard to distill my code into a simple example, so I am sorry. It is something very complicated to breakdown. But still the question is: what does `max() arg is an empty sequence` mean when associated with `max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len)`?

Comment: It means that `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)` is an empty sequence. But more useful is to know *why* that happens, for which we'd need more code.

Comment: I know `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)` returns a generator. I am open to the possibility that one of the loading events has brought down the entire network, resulting in `0` active nodes. In this case, I assume the generator would be empty. Is this sensible? Given this case, I would like to skip the `error` by telling it to simply return `0` as `max` value, which would imply all my nodes have failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94614/discussion-between-francesco-castellani-and-interjay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What does `max() arg is an empty sequence` mean when associated with `max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G), key=len)`?"

It means exactly what it says: the argument of `max` is an empty sequence.  More specifically `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)` is empty.  As far as I know, the only thing that would lead to that is if `G` has no nodes.